# Why can't I remove images from my UICollectoinView?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a simple setup. There is a button that acts as a toggle switch. If it is enabled, the user should be able to remove photos by simply tapping on them. If it is not enabled, then nothing happens when tapped on.

I set the toggle variable `remove` initially to false. When tapped, the button changes images and change `remove` to true.

```
var remove = false

@IBAction func removeButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    if remove == false {
        let image1 = UIImage(named: "Minus_sign_of_a_line_in_horizontal_position_64 (2)") as UIImage!
        removeButtonAppearance.setImage(image1, forState: .Normal)
        remove = true
    } else if remove == true {
        let image2 = UIImage(named: "Minus_sign_of_a_line_in_horizontal_position_64") as UIImage!
        removeButtonAppearance.setImage(image2, forState: .Normal)
        remove = false
    }
}
```

Fast forward to my `UICollectionView` code.

Using the `didSelectItemAtIndexPath()` function, I check to see if `remove` is true, and if it is, I attempt to empty the cell and reload the `UICollectionView`'s data.

This is where I run into problems. Simply put, nothing happens when tapped. If I remove the check for `remove`, however, it works fine. What am I doing wrong?

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        if collectionView == collectionView2 {
            let cell: ConfirmRequestsCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ConfirmRequestsCollectionViewCell
            if remove == true {
                requestsArray.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
                images2.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
                self.collectionView2.reloadData()
            }
        } else {
            let cell: ConfirmOffersCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ConfirmOffersCollectionViewCell
            if remove == true {
                offersArray.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
                images1.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
                self.collectionView1.reloadData()
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: It's all but impossible to tell what's wrong by looking at your code. 

Time to set some breakpoints and walk through it. Is your removeButton action code firing?

Is the didSelectItemAtIndexPath method being called? Set a breakpoint at the very top and then step through it.

Answer (score 0):

My `remove` variable was local. I switched it to global, and everything works now!